# How to Insert data into self reference table in sql server?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

What is the the query for inserting data into a self-referencing table. My table has 4 columns: `SlNo`, `Name` , `ParentId` , `CurrentBanlance`.

I tried this SQL query but it doesn't execute, is there any another way?

```
INSERT INTO Ptr_AcntInfo 
   SELECT 
       '" + txtAcName.Text + "',
       (SELECT [SlNo] FROM Ptr_AcntInfo WHERE [Ac_Nm] = '" + cbxAcntGrpName.Text + "'),"+0.00+""
```

In this query I am getting the below error.

> *Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.*

Comment: your (select [SlNo] from Ptr_AcntInfo where[Ac_Nm]='" + cbxAcntGrpName.Text + "') query will always return one SlNo?

Comment: it shows error like   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: If you have changes you'd like to make to your question, you should *edit* the existing question, not post a new one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query should look like:

```
"INSERT INTO PTR_ACNTINFO (COL1, COL2)
(SELECT " + txtAcName.Text + ", SINo FROM
PTR_ACNTINFO
WHERE [Ac_Nm]='" + cbxAcntGrpName.Text + "')"
```

Note this query is vulnerable to `SQL Injection` attacks.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

You should use parameterised queries or a stored procedure.

**Example:**

```
SQLCommand sqlCommand = new SQLCommand(connection); 
sqlCommand.CommandText =  "INSERT INTO PTR_ACNTINFO (SELECT $name, SINo FROM
                           PTR_ACNTINFO WHERE [Ac_Nm]='$accNo')"

sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("$name", txtAcName.Text);
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("$accNo", cbxAcntGrpName.Text);
```

http://johnhforrest.com/2010/10/parameterized-sql-queries-in-c/

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it shows error as          Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.

Comment: @NareshJ I have updatedd my post. Replace COL1 and COL2 with your column names.